# "One of Hyper-V components is not running", Linux in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: linux, debian, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, hypervisor

I am trying to get Debian working in the host Windows Server 2012 R2. The Windows Server is running on other host, macOS with Parallels. I am getting the following error `One of Hyper-V components is not running`. Debian 9.1.0 is not listed in the supported VMs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-debian-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v) and only older Debians are mentioned, could this cause the error?

**How to resolve this error `One of Hyper-V components is not running`?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run Hyper-V as a nested hypervisor. It must have recognized that Parallels doesn't expose required features to Windows Server VM and hence, Hyper-V hypervisor itself is not running.
Have a look at Server manager and\or event log on Windows Server, it will most probably have an error, explaining that required hardware features are not present on the host to start Hyper-V.

Parallels describes how to enable Nested virtualisation support in [this Knowledge Base article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/116239) on their official site.